# Entity Extraction from a .CSV File

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract a specific part of a column in a .CSV file using Python and Pandas. I have the .CSV file read in already. There is a column with the data I need to extract, and another column with a lot of information in it, and that data is a part of that column as well. I was thinking about trying to store the column with the data already in it into an array then trying to use a search algorithm or something like that to find and return the data from the second column, but I'm unsure on how to do that. Any advice for a better approach or tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: search for Regex.

Comment: Place some of the data from the file and the code in which you tried to do something. Questions without code, even with errors, are not welcome here. Then it will be much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used pandas but it looks like you use

> `pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer,  index_col=None)`
>
> [Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into
> DataFrame.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

python also has builtin csv support https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html